# Converting prices in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataframe with the lines corresponding to different clothing items. I have two columns with prices and the syntax looks like this:

| price | rrp |
| --- | --- |
| 5.00 | 8.00 |
| 5 | 7.50 |
| 5.0 | 9.0 |

I want to convert these so that prices like 5.00/5.0 are converted to 5, but values like 7.50 stay the same. I've tried converting the values to integers, but this is not possible for values like 8.00. I've also tried to use:

```py
df['price'].str.replace('.00', '').replace('.0', '')
```

But this results in a lot of values being empty. Anyone got a solution for me?

Comment: You cannot do this with numerical values, only with strings

Comment: What's the problem you *really* want to solve? Formatting this as output somewhere? What kind of display? Maybe it should be solved as part of the display, not the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 What you want only makes sense for strings, so convert everything to strings

2  `replace` accepts regex

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'price':['5.00', '5', '5.0'], 'rrp':['8.00', '7.50', '9.0']})
df = df.astype(str).replace({'\.00':'', '\.0':''}, regex=True)
print(df)
```